# Should you ever duplicate data?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

This is a very general question about database design in regards to products that have multiple running campaigns that may share data sets. I'm trying to understand concepts on why I should and should not do something like this.

I was thinking of having a raw set of data, and then copying a part of that set over to the campaign so that the campaign will always have historical data. For example, even if the raw data updates, the campaign's data wouldn't change. However, the issue is that there is just so much duplication and I'm not sure if that's a very good design. Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Your question is quite open-ended, and runs the risk of being flagged since it will generate opinion-based answers. It might be better to frame it specifically in terms of your current requirement and the problem you're facing with not duplicating data, and the risk you see with duplicating data.

Comment: That said, in general, there are valid cases where the challenges associated with duplicated data are lesser than the "cost" of keeping data normalized and not duplicated. Data warehousing is the classic example where data duplication is acceptable (rather, recommended) given certain constraints (e.g. data not changing).

Comment: Likewise, it might make sense for your case to duplicate data, provided careful thought has gone into the whys behind it, and its not being done just because its quicker/easier today, but leads to a can of worms somewhere down the line.

Comment: If your "raw set of data" is used as a template to seed the campaign, and the campaign then becomes standalone, then this form of duplication is fine. If you have a requirement to keep history of the raw data itself, then you might have to use a [type-2 design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row), wherein the raw data is timestamped to show the periods it was effective from/to. In such a case, there wouldn't be a need to duplicate data into the campaign, as you can refer to relevant historical rows in the raw data itself.

Comment: @Phylyp I do realize that it is very open ended and I'm not really sure where's the appropriate place to ask this.

Comment: @Phylyp The more I think about it, the more I realize I'm not sure if my "reasons" are enough to justify such an expensive duplication. Yes, it will be standalone. I'm also placing strong value on flexibility, because I don't know how the product will grow yet. However, I think I am currently attracted by how much easier it is to do queries if I just copied it.

Comment: Is this something you're building for a customer, or just something you're doing for yourself? For a customer - especially a paying one - it's important to deliver the right thing, but if its just for yourself (or something that you will actively own support of), you can consider going with the easier approach now (i.e. duplication), just bearing in mind (and documenting) specific decisions that you will change when you come to a point when you do want to change it.

Comment: If your campaign is standalone after being created from the raw data, then it is fine to duplicate the raw data to give the campaign a snapshot of the raw data at that point in time. However, do ask yourself if there will ever be a case where someone wonders why a particular bit of data in campaign A is different from the same bit in campaign B, where you'd have to explain that it changed between the time campaigns A and B were created. And then ask yourself if that explanation will be accepted, or will the user then ask you for that data to be reflected identically in both campaigns.

Comment: What % of data would be updated (so that they are diff for diff campaigns)? How  many campaigns are there (just a few or hundreds?). If % of data updates are not high, you can consider not updating the rows; instead adding a new row when old data needs to be updated. Mark the rows with a timestamp. Then get the campaigns to use the data within a certain timestamp...  consider creating views/indexes on subset of data (some databases allow index on subset of data)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, this is a great question. Database design for transactional or OLTP systems does seek to eliminate storing the same information in more than one place.

That said, storing historical values does not violate data redundancy. You are actually storing a value that is different from your normal transactional data.

For instance, let's say you have a sales region associated with a particular customer on the customer table. When you capture a Sale, you may wish to store the region on the Sales Order Header table. This is not necessarily duplication of data, but rather good design in the case where Sales Regions may change. In this case, you may want to capture the region that applied to the order at the time of the order.

Tomorrow, the customer's region may change. And you will be able to create reports based upon the historically correct region.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question depends on the project's priorities.

If being able to look at historical data is an essential requirement then such duplication will be needed. There will be a subset of tables that need to be "versioned". For example, you may have a `product_version` table with `date_from` and `date_to` columns specifying when it is/was effective. Or you might go further and put the version details in an `abstract_version` table, which holds the version details (e.g. period and status) and is referenced by all versioned tables via foreign keys. Whenever a new version is created, it will initially need to take a copy of the old data and then allow it to be modified.

But such an approach will inevitably come at the expense of increased complexity. For some anecdotal evidence, the project I'm working on right now is a large project that has gone significantly over the original budget - not least because of the complexities involved in maintaining historical data.

Answer (score 1):

When you see data repetition, you refer to data in a row with other row on same table.  If there is a practical situation that we can have two rows with same value possible, it can't be considered as data repetition.  At least time-stamp of that row will be different.  On worst case, if we think that in one mSec, both rows are entered and time-stamp can be same, then the entered person must be different.  In a nutshell, if there are two rows with same values, it is practically possible and functionally it must be correct as there will be some hidden values that can make them different like campaign number, participant, time-stamp, etc.

Considering data archival strategy and worth of the persisted data (if there is business value / need of governance) must be evaluated.  If there is no business value like using it for DWH, Mining, etc, it is advisable to have archival DB so that OLTP uses DB effectively.

For you, if historical campaign data adds value to end-user (like showing in charts) or management (to show any trend of response / to explain repeated behavior in campaign), it is useful.  Else, I don't find reason to store in same table.